# Any way to trigger an 'onchange' function call when a value is changed by an AJAX value return?

Tags: html, ajax, onchange

I have several drop down menus with a

```
<... onchange="callthisfunction(...)"...>
```

When a user manually changes the value the function is called easily enough, but when I use an ajax call to load saved data back into my page, it does not register the drop down value as being changed, and the function call is not triggered. Is there a way to ensure this gets triggered when the value is changed via ajax?

Comment: What part of the ajax code changes the dropdown value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById("id").onchange()
```

to generate an onchange event programmatically or you can even call "callthisfunction()" when your ajax call changes the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

```
 onchange:function(){
 //temp()
}

 afterAjaxSuccess:function(){
 //temp();
}

temp:function(){
//code when dropdown is changed or after a service call is made to trigger this function
}
```